# swiftly generate and sort full encoding dictionary and corresponding primary radicals

Tags: character-encoding, command-line-interface, stanford-nlp

Chinese characters, [according to the unihan encoding schema](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr38/#N101E4), can be indexed by their primary radical.

The [Stanford Word Segmenter](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/segmenter.shtml) has a command that can execute this, as described in their [documentation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/international/pennchinese/RadicalMap.html) i.e.

```
java -cp stanford-segmenter-VERSION.jar
edu.stanford.nlp.trees.international.pennchinese.RadicalMap
-infile whitespace_seperated_chinese_characters.input
> each_character_denoted_by_radical.output
```

I want to create a comprehensive table of chinese characters organized by their primary radical, I suppose I can use the function

**public static java.util.Set getChars(char ch)**

*What are the Characters with this primary radical?*

or

**public static char getRadical(char ch)**

*What is the primary radical of this char?*

But my question is, what is the most efficacious way to accomplish this goal? and furthermore to output the result in the form of a table, [à la this Wikipedia table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification#Examples_of_language_independent_characters) (not exactly like that table, but, shall we say, suggestive of that table).

That Stanford tool uses the [CC-CEDIT](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=cedict) dictionary. Is it possible I could just download that dictionary and feed it in? If so, how?

Maybe than Stanford tool already contains this as [part of the code](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/tree/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/international/pennchinese), but how to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is encoded in exactly the form you want in the [`RadicalMap` source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/international/pennchinese/RadicalMap.java).

See the static initializer:

```
String[] radLists = {"\u4e00\u4e00\u4e01\u4e02\u4e03...", "...", ..., };
```

Each string in this list has as its first character a radical, and the remaining characters have that first character as their primary radical.

It's a package-local static variable, so there's not exactly a clean way to access it programmatically.. but you could easily rip its definition out of the source code and use it for whatever need you have.